# Index of a numbered array of key:value in Mustache.js

Tags: json, mustache

I have this object:

```
{nodes: [
        {
            node: {
                actors: {
                    1: "Actor 1",
                    2: "Actor 2"
                }
            }
        }]
```

In my Mustache template, I tried this and it worked:

```
{{#actors}}
   {{1}}<br />
   {{2}}
{{/actors}}
```

But I dont know how much actors I have, I need something like an index. It seems that handlebars.js knows how to do this, but I want to use Mustache.js.

Comment: Is the strange part of that JSON the fact that `actors` is not an array?

Comment: Yes, it is an object; I just understand that... But it does not help me solve the problem either.

Comment: The problem is that you want a way to iterate over all of an object's properties. That is a valid question, but you can easily solve this problem by treating `actors` as a list of objects, and not an object. Mustache already has the ability to iterate over a list. Is this JSON coming from an external server?

Comment: I'm working on a local copy. You can visualize JSON data here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/773169/data.json . My problem is for comediens, Chanteurs, photos

Comment: Cool, so you have control over the JSON. My answer describes how you can change the format to make it easier using Mustache.

Comment: No, I don't have control, it is a saved version of a Drupal view.

Comment: If the JSON cannot change, then you can transform it into a list when you receive it on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the format of the JSON so it is like:

```
"actors": [ {"name": "Actor 1"}, {"name": "Actor 2"}]
```

Then you can do

```
{{#actors}}
  {{name}}
{{/actors}}
```

If you wanted to use Handlebars, you can specify a helper for this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachProperty', function (context, options) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var prop in context) {
        if (prop)
            ret = ret + options.fn(({ property: prop, value: JSON.stringify(context[prop]) }));
    }
    return ret;
});
```

So when you wanted to iterate over an object's properties, you can do:

```
{{#eachProperty actors}}
  {{value}}
{{/eachProperty}}
```

Also note that `{{property}}` would give you the index value for the object.

Comment: Of course it will work with this change, but I can't control my JSON data in the future.

Comment: Then you should consider using Handlebars. I don't think there is a way to achieve what you intend in Mustache. Is there a reason why you prefer not to use Handlebars?

Comment: It seems much more complicated, and I'm not even sure how to solve this problem with it.

Comment: I included what you can use in Handlebars to solve this.